# MultiPeer Framework Delegates Not Firing/Running (No UI)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, multipeer-connectivity

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. I'm trying test the multi peer framework. And I'm trying to do it without a UI. In other words, I'm inviting other peers manually through code. I want to be able for the app to come up, and the peers automatically start looking for each other and connect.

To do this I set up a class named **SideWaysManager** as so:

```
/**
  SidewaysManager.m
*/

#import "SidewaysManager.h"
#import "EPBmyConfig.h"

@implementation SidewaysManager
{
    NSString *databasePath;

    MCSession *currentSession;

    MCNearbyServiceBrowser *nearbyBrowser;

    MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *nearbyAdvertiser;

    NSString *serviceType;
}



- (id) init
{

    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {

        EPBmyConfig *configInfo = [EPBmyConfig instance];

        NSString *assetID = [configInfo getAssetID];

        NSString *useageLocation = [configInfo getUseageLocation];

        NSString *peerDisplayName = [@"PCTouchPad-" stringByAppendingString:assetID];

        if(![useageLocation isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            peerDisplayName = [peerDisplayName stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", useageLocation]];
        }

        MCPeerID *localPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:peerDisplayName];

        currentSession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:localPeerID];
        currentSession.delegate = self;

        serviceType = @"EPB-Session";

        nearbyBrowser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:localPeerID serviceType:serviceType];
        nearbyBrowser.delegate = self;

        nearbyAdvertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:localPeerID discoveryInfo:nil serviceType:serviceType];
        nearbyAdvertiser.delegate = self;


        NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

        databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingString:@"/voterdb_Prod"];

        [nearbyAdvertiser startAdvertisingPeer];

        [nearbyBrowser startBrowsingForPeers];

        return self;
    }

    return self;

}

/**

 Session delegates
 */

// Remote peer changed state
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state
{
    if(state == MCSessionStateConnected)
    {
        [nearbyAdvertiser stopAdvertisingPeer];
        [nearbyBrowser stopBrowsingForPeers];

        NSLog(@"Peer connected to session");
    }
    else if(state == MCSessionStateNotConnected)
    {
        NSLog(@"Peer not connected");
    }
}

// Received data from remote peer
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
{
}

// Start receiving a resource from remote peer
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didStartReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withProgress:(NSProgress *)progress
{
}

// Finished receiving a resource from remote peer and saved the content in a temporary location - the app is responsible for moving the file to a permanent location within its sandbox
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didFinishReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID atURL:(NSURL *)localURL withError:(NSError *)error
{
}

- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveCertificate:(NSArray *)certificate fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID certificateHandler:(void(^)(BOOL accept))certificateHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Received certificate");
    certificateHandler(YES);
}

- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveStream:(NSInputStream *)stream withName:(NSString *)streamName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
{
    stream.delegate = self;

    [stream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [stream open];

}



/**
 MCBrowser Delegates
 */

// Found a nearby advertising peer
- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"Found Peer");

    [browser invitePeer:peerID toSession:currentSession withContext:nil timeout:0];
}

// A nearby peer has stopped advertising
- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser lostPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
{
    NSLog(@"Lost Peer");
}



/**Advertising Delegates
 */

- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withContext:(NSData *)context invitationHandler:(void(^)(BOOL accept, MCSession *session))invitationHandler
{
    invitationHandler(YES, currentSession);
}


// Advertising did not start due to an error
- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didNotStartAdvertisingPeer:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Did not start advertising");
}


@end
```

And here's my SideWaysManager.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MultipeerConnectivity/MultipeerConnectivity.h>

@interface SidewaysManager : NSObject <MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCSessionDelegate, NSStreamDelegate>


@end
```

And then I initialize this class in my AppDelegate class. But, for some reason **NONE** of the delegate methods above run. Can any one familiar with the framework help me out or have any idea why nothing is happening in this class? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a project based on the Single View Application template. I added your SideWaysManager code to the project. To make it compile I removed the EPBmyConfig import and fixed the compilation errors as shown below:

```
//     EPBmyConfig *configInfo = [EPBmyConfig instance]; 

//     NSString *assetID = [configInfo getAssetID];

//     NSString *useageLocation = [configInfo getUseageLocation]; 

       NSString *peerDisplayName = @"PCTouchPad-Test";

//    if(![useageLocation isEqualToString:@""])
//    {
//        peerDisplayName = [peerDisplayName stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", useageLocation]];
//    }

      MCPeerID *localPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:peerDisplayName];
```

Running the code on my iPhone and simulator the delegates methods were called and a session was created. So it seems that your setup of the Multipeer Connectivity objects is OK.

How do you create the SideWaysManager in your AppDelegate?

This is how I did it:

```
@interface PFAppDelegate ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) SidewaysManager *manager;

@end


@implementation PFAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.manager = [[SidewaysManager alloc]init];
    return YES;
}
```

It is important that your AppDelegate class holds a reference to the manager, otherwise it will be de-alloced immediately after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions returns. This could explain that nothing happens in your code.

Alternatively, their might be a problem in the creation of the peer display name (basically the stuff that I commented out).

Comment: Thanks a lot for loading it up in your project and giving it a go. I was actually able to find the solution, but forgot to update it here. Yes, my problem was that I didn't have a property or instance variable for sideways manager. It was deallocated immediately since it was a local variable.

Comment: I"m going to give you credit since you got the same exact solution and you loaded my file up.